# Laravel JS file path when included in View it appends namespace in the path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am using following code to call my js file that further calls all other files

```
 {{ HTML::script('js/script.js') }}
```

i want following URI

```
pathToMyProject/js/jquery.ui.totop.js // as laravell loads its files
```

what i am getting is

```
pathToMyProject/employees/js/jquery.ui.totop.js"
```

just to mention i am calling the js files from `Views/Employees/Layouts/Main` and my js is in `public/js/allFiles`

Comment: try `{{ HTML::script('/js/script.js') }}`

Comment: @Saqueib
I am still getting following error dude:
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.emr.dev/employees/js/jquery.ui.totop.js"

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Laravel 4 I will suggest you to use below method to src the script

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/script.js') }}"></script>
```

**URL::asset** will link to your `project/public/js/script.js` folder.

Make sure you are using `php artisan serve` command to serve your app.

If above not worked, I will suggest you to add a bese tag in header also

```
<header>
...
<base href="/" target="_top">
```

and then use your code

```
{{ HTML::script('js/script.js') }}
```

**Note:** You'll need to be using blade templates with `.blade.php` extension  to use this.